# SwiperJS Card Layout Integration

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Code Reference: [Example At Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-framework-hz4tyt?file=/index.html)

I want to be able to swiper or click the swiper navigation buttons, such that it only traverse 1 slide at a time with this layout. Which is a `slidesPerView: "auto"` with a fixed width. The first two slides in the link shows the expected behaviour but when the last two slides come into view it gets stuck on '2/4, am I missing an extra argument to be passed in swiper options?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WagaJ.png)

I tried the following:

- passed `slidesPerView: "auto"`in Swiper instantiation. and gave my `swiper-slide` element a fixed width
- passed `slidesPerView: 1` in Swiper instantiation. and gave my `swiper-slide` element a fixed width

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Swiper slider has a [fractional pagination parameter](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-type):
[**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-glade-8tq3sp)

Comment: I've tried using the fraction parameter, while it does show the ' 1 out of x' pagination which is the correct out come. The active index should be the first on the left most of the screen.